# IPC standards to ask manufacturer to assure a PCBA is correctly manufactured?

Tags: manufacturing, ipc

I'm preparing all the documentation to send to my PCBA manufacturing supplier and I wonder if there's a list of IPC standards to include in this documentation and verify they are compliant to them and assure its capabilities of manufacturing the PCBA under these IPCs.

The PCBA is a 4 layer PCB, 100% SMT, 0,4mm minimum pitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IPC-A-610](https://www.ipc.org/TOC/IPC-A-610G.pdf) covers placement and assembly.

Remember that your PCB design should meet the requirements under [IPC-2221B](https://www.ipc.org/TOC/IPC-2221B.pdf) as it covers both PCB layout and component footprint design, for a proper placement and assembly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Does "assembly phase" cover also soldering? Regarding stencil, solder paste etc...Is there any additional IPC required?

Comment: @LazyTurtle yes. It covers soldering criteria for THT and SMD components as well as cables.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @LazyTurtle Stencil and solder paste requirements are under 2221B / SMD footprint and pad design. So "your design" should be compliant to this. You can't expect the PCBA company should comply to this.

Comment: @LazyTurtle you may accept my answer if satisfactory enough, so that the question does not remain open.